# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }n!(2x-1)^n$

Tags: calculus, power-series

I get to the point of $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }(n+1)\left | 2x-1 \right |$ using the ratio test. It looks like it should always diverge but I'm not sure. Also not sure what the x=0.5 case does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the ratio test gives $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }(n+1)\left | 2x-1 \right |$. If $x\ne 0$ this obviously diverges to $+\infty$, and the limit is zero for $x=0$. Therefore, the radius of convergence is zero.

If you want the series to be an actual power series, though, you should look at

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }2^n n!\left(x-\frac 12\right)^n$$

This gives you the same result.

You then need to check what happens at the endpoints of the interval of convergence. The interval has radius zero around the point $x=\frac 12$, so there is just one endpoint, $x=\frac 12$. For that value every term in the sum is zero, so the total sum is also zero.

Therefore the series converges only for $x=\frac 12$.

Comment: Ok and for the notation of the interval notation should i put I={0.5} or I = [0.5]?

Comment: @Tyler: Perhaps $[0.5,0.5]$, though that also means $\{0.5\}$. Your last choice $[0.5]$ is not clear and should be avoided.